# How do I treat missing namespace warning as an error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, build

Can someone please help me treat the following warning as an error? One of our dev setups (a build machine) treats this issue as an error, others (developers' machines) as a warning. I can't seem to find anything online regarding this.

> Namespace or type specified in the Imports
>   'Your.Nonexistent.Namespace' doesn't contain any public member or
>   cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and
>   contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element
>   name doesn't use any aliases. C:\Yourproject\yourClass.vb

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://visualstudiotips.wordpress.com/2006/04/16/tip-treat-warnings-as-errors/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to treat all warnings as errors at this point.

Comment: Pretty sure that it's either on or off.  You might be able to set-up a stylecop rule for it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Project Properties page Compile tab there is a checkbox labled Treat all warnings as errors.  this w

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to treat all warnings as errors at this point.